# How can pagination links be handeld after an axios call with post method in React?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, post, pagination

I use React frontend and Laravel backed.
I've got an api call with post method. It's aim is to get filtered result based on the payload:

```
axiosClient.post('/admin/filter_tasks', payload)
.then(({ data }) => {
    setTasks(data)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

After this api call I get paginated response with page links in it:

```
links: Array(4)
0: {url: null, label: '&laquo; Previous', active: false}
1: {url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/admin/filter_tasks?page=1', label: '1', active: true}
2: {url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/admin/filter_tasks?page=2', label: '2', active: false}
3: {url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/admin/filter_tasks?page=2', label: 'Next &raquo;', active: false}
length: 4
```

I tried to use these links to get the pages but they cannot be accessed with get method.
How can I use the links to get the pages?

Comment: What error are you getting? And how are you trying to access those URLs with Axios?

Comment: Its the same endpoint, so you need to use **POST** requests

Answer (score 0):

1. As Bob mentioned **post** method is needed. (Thanks.)
2. The **original payload needs to be added** to every axios call, even if it is a certain page call eg.: 'http://localhost:8000/api/admin/filter_tasks?page=2'

The original payload can be stored and reused with the help of a useState hook.